# How to dual boot with Windows 7 on an Ubuntu-only system?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Well basically, I have a 500GB hard drive with Ubuntu 12.04 installed (Only OS at the moment). I plan to install Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit on a 50GB partition and dual boot it with Ubuntu. Does anyone know how? Thanks!